# Distance From A Point To Cube

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose I have closed cube $Q$ and $Q^*$ with the same center in $n$-dimensional real space with side of $Q^*$ is $2\sqrt{n}$ longer than side of $Q$. Suppose I also have a point $x$ outside $Q^*$ with given distance $r$ with a point $y\in Q$. I want to prove there exists a ball of radius $\alpha(n)r$ with center $x$ such that it does not intersect $Q$ ($\alpha(n)$ means a positive constant depends only on the dimension, not on the cube or the chosen point on cube). I tried to use triangle inequality like this :

Suppose $x$ has farthest distance with $p\in Q$. Then for arbitrary $z\in Q$
\begin{align*}
|x-z|\geq |x-p|-|p-z|\geq |x-p|-\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n}-1}r
\end{align*}
But if $y=p=z$, the lower bound will be negative constant, which is not good enough. Can one handle the problem with another method?

Comment: Are the sides of $Q$ and $Q^*$ parallel, or can they be oriented independently from each other?

Comment: @PaulSinclair parallel